# IP barrado em blacklist

Tags: redes, zabbix, spam

Tenho um ip que foi barrado numa blacklist. A mensagem que aparece no zabbix é a seguinte: `"xxx.xx.xx.xxx Listed in dnsbl.othello.ch"`. Onde `xxx.xx.xx.xxx` seria o ip.

Vocês sabem como posso fazer para remover essa IP dessa lista de spam?

Comment: Segue o passo a passo. --> [link](https://www.dnslink.com.br/site/2015/05/24/como-desbloquear-ips-firewall/)

Comment: Bom dia! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O host destino esta utilizando o mod_dnsbl, e deixou ativo na configuraçao de exemplo, no caso, com o nome othello.ch (hostname).
Basta solicitar ao administrador desse host que retire seu ip da black list.